# Importing a pfx certificate using Import-PfxCertificate

Tags: powershell, cmake, azure-devops, certificate, pfx

I am trying to import a pfx certificate using this command:

```
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath deleteme\App1\App1\Windows_TemporaryKey.pfx -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My
```

This runs on an Azure DevOps agent and it terminates with the following error:

```
2021-08-17T08:12:41.8589900Z Import-PfxCertificate : The PFX file you are trying to import requires either a different password or membership in an 
2021-08-17T08:12:41.8843817Z Active Directory principal to which it is protected.
2021-08-17T08:12:41.9009498Z At D:\Agents\02-V2\_work\_temp\ea432c03-2d7e-41d0-b921-60675873b966.ps1:5 char:1
2021-08-17T08:12:41.9091156Z + & Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath deleteme\App1\App1\Windows_Temporar ...
2021-08-17T08:12:41.9275703Z + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2021-08-17T08:12:41.9332015Z     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-PfxCertificate], Win32Exception
2021-08-17T08:12:41.9657873Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.ImportPfxCer 
2021-08-17T08:12:41.9940803Z    tificate
```

Now, I have seen plenty of stackoverflow posts dealing with this error, but all of them were for certificates which actually had private keys. This one has no private key (at least I have not been prompted to enter one when importing it on my local machine) and it is actually the template CMake pfx file, which I believe comes with every Windows CMake distribution (in the cmake-x.xx.x-windows-x86_64\share\cmake-x.xx\Templates\Windows directory). So I am intereseted in the second part of the error message: the membership in the "Active Directory principal to which it is protected". This is already pretty cryptic for me. The pfx has some principal associated with it? I haven't seen any such properties when inspecting the pfx using the Open command in the file's context menu. Or the current user has to have some AD principal associated? If it is so, which one?

To put this whole Import-PfxCertificate effort into context - it is part of me trying to automatically build an UWP app in CI, but CMake refuses to pass the ARM64 compiler checks exactly because it can not import this particular certificate (it is possible to import it without problems on all of my local machines). I know that I am able to force CMake to skip those compiler checks but I would need to be able to import certificates anyway to sign the app, so I think I would hit that problem again anyways.

Comment: Looks like you [can tell CMake which password to use](https://github.com/Monetra/mstdlib/blob/master/CMakeModules/CodeSign.cmake#L7-L17) - tell it to use a specific password, then use the same password when importing

Comment: As mentioned in the question, it is the cmake compiler check. Its built-in certificate Windows_TemporaryKey.pfx has no password. I probably forgot to elaborate that me running the Import-PfxCertificate command is just to try to see if the certificate import works well without involving CMake at all.